# iOS [Obj-C] segue based on matching keys in different MySQL tables in same DB

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, xcode6, segue

CatViewController.m :

```
categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.count; i++)
{
    NSString * cID = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"categoryID"];
    NSString * cDesc = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"categoryDesc"];
    NSString * cName = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"categoryName"];

    [categoryArray addObject:[[Categories alloc]initWidthCategoryDesc:cDesc andcategoryName:cName andcategoryID:cID]];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"catToTopic" sender:(self)];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"catToTopic"]) {
        TopicViewController *topViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        topViewController.data = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

TopicViewController.m:

```
topicArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray3.count; i++)
{
    NSString * rID = [[jsonArray3 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"replyID"];
    NSString * rTopic = [[jsonArray3 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"replyTopic"];
    NSString * rDate = [[jsonArray3 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"replyDate"];
    NSString * rContent = [[jsonArray3 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"replyContent"];
    NSString * rBy = [[jsonArray3 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"replyBy"];

    [topicArray addObject:[[Posts alloc]initWidthReplyBy: rBy andreplyDate: rDate andreplyTopic: rTopic andreplyContent: rContent andreplyID: rID]];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

So the issue I'm having is, instead of clicking a row in CatViewController and just segueing into a new view and populating every reply in TopicViewController, I want to match categoryID to replyTopic and populate only the matching entries

the hierarchical data passing is giving me a headache! I'm not even looking for a handout, just a place where I can get a good read and headstart on the topic!

trying to set *data in CatViewController to catID didn't work, and even if it did - I can't figure out how to use it in TopicViewController to do a subquery on to populate the information...

Comment: I guess, if I can pass along the catID to TopicViewController, I can put an if (replyTopic = catID) inside of the for loop to only pull those records? or would that not work....

Comment: The if statement should be ==, apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay -- here's a quick response to get you started.

In your TopicViewController.h (the header) add:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * rID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * rTopic;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * rDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * rContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * rBy;
```

Change your CatViewController.m prepareForSegue method to be this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"catToTopic"]) {
        TopicViewController *topViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        topViewController.rID = [[self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"replyID"];
        topViewController.rTopic = [[self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"replyTopic"];
        topViewController.rDate = [[self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"replyDate"];
        topViewController.rComment = [[self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"replyComment"];
        topViewController.rBy = [[self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"replyBy"];
    }
}
```

And then change the TopicViewController.m viewDidLoad (or viewDidAppear, wherever you have it), to call:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

===

Based on your comments, I think what you want to do is:

TopicViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *theData;
```

prepareForSegue:

```
topViewController.theData = [jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: I'm assuming that [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row] is the same thing as the json data.  If not, I think you can still get that within your CatViewController, right?

Comment: yeah, TVC is populating correctly - my problem is pulling categoryID from CVC segueing it, and then using it to only populate the UITableView in TVC with the replyTopics that match categoryID

Comment: Then would creating a property on TVC to be NSString *categoryID and setting it in the prepareSegue do what you need?

Comment: see my thing is i'm super confused on whether I need an actual dictionary or if I can just pull the information from jsonArray2 - dang, you cant even see jsonArray2 - _jsonArray2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];_
 **output snippet:**
        _( {
        categoryDesc = "Attempt at an actual catefory";
        categoryID = 2;
        categoryName = TestCat;
    },{
        categoryDesc = "kjnk,m";
        categ_ **...** or do i need to crate a dictionary from that info to actually use 'categoryID' as an NSInteger or NSString to pass through?

Comment: [HERE's a LINK](http://tandemenvoy.michaeldvinci.com/forum/categoriesJSON.php) to the actual JSON.php file if that'll help

Comment: just use it as is.  You can pass anything to TVC that you want -- do it in the easiest way, but only send what you want to display (don't make TVC handle parsing out stuff it ignores).

Comment: That php link helped.  So you can send an NSDictionary from within the NSArray as a property.

Comment: so since I'm using a UITableView and I'm having it get the categoryID from the specific row I choose, do I use _tVC.passedData = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:(@"categoryID")];_  ??  **edit** sorry tVC is my segue variable and data is now 'passedData' I was up till 4 trying different things out

Comment: ah sorry about that, still getting used to not just scouring SO for other issues! -- ok so I tried it out, but in TVC I tried this, _- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    //test to see what gets passed along
    NSLog(@"passed: %@", theData);_ just to see, but i still get a _passsed: (null)_ output

Comment: great -- try it in viewDidAppear

Comment: yupp _- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //test to see what gets passed along
    NSLog(@"passed: %@", theData);
}_ still outputs _2015-03-12 12:06:58.948 Aviato[1333:54770] passed: (null)_

Comment: put a breakpoint where it sets the data (in the prepareForSegue) and see if that value is being created (or NSLog it there).

Comment: for some reason, even though it's set to Debug in Scheme, my breakpoints arent working =/  --- [we're talking about NSLog'ing it in the prepareForSegue, right?]

Comment: Yes.  Either before or after you set it.

Comment: first of all, I must commend and than kyou or al lthe help you're offering... secondly
        _NSLog(@"test: %@",[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        
        tVC.theData = [jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];_ outputs absolutely nothing, and then it just segues regardless

Comment: is the name of the segue the same in the Storyboard as it is in the prepareForSegue?  For the first line of prepareForSegue, could you do this: NSLog (@"segue: %@", segue.identifier);

Comment: = |  . amazing. I cant believe I forgot to set it back after I changed from a UITableViewController to a UITableView within a UIViewController. everything shows, theTest passes through , you, sir, are a godsend. Marked as solved, and you sir, have my undying gratitude